# Azure AD read extended attributes

Tags: azure, active-directory

Is there a way to expose user extension attribute properties with Open Graph on Azure AD (Ideally we would want sync'd information held in these properties to be exposed by Open Graph)?

Answer (score 2):

Very old post but putting answer out there in case someone hits this one.

This information is exposed through the graph today. This can be viewed at https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/# on api-version=1.6

Go to the bottom of the GET value response and it will like:

```
"extension_291ab83da7c34fa0b02c5cbaba6f35ef_employeeID": "12215",
"extension_291ab83da7c34fa0b02c5cbaba6f35ef_accountExpires@odata.type": "Edm.Int64",
"extension_291ab83da7c34fa0b02c5cbaba6f35ef_accountExpires": "9223372036854775807"
```

The format for Directory Extension from Azure AD Connect is:

**extension + Unique GUID + Attribute Name**

Azure AD requires uniqueness hence the GUID value it attaches in the middle separated by an underscore.